# Appbar fitsSystemWindows - Inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, statusbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an Activity that contains a `ViewPager`:

> `activity.xml:`
>
> ```
> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
>
>     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>         android:id="@+id/pager"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

The fragments this pager contains – which are all generated from the same layout – have a `CoordinatorLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to provide a collapsing image-back titlebar:

> `fragment.xml:`
>
> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
>
>     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
>         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
>
>         <!-- Content here -->
>
>     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>         android:id="@+id/appbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="256dp"
>         android:elevation="8dp"
>         android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
>
>         <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>             android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
>             app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
>             android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/photo"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>                 app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
>                 android:background="@color/photo_placeholder"
>                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
>
>             <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>                 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>                 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
>                 app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
>                 android:layout_gravity="bottom">
>
>             </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
>
>         </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
>
>     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

Without the `fitsSystemWindows` flags in the activity layout, the image in the fragment properly displays behind the system status bar, while the text sometimes collapses behind the status bar when scrolled up. If I add the flags in – as shown above – the text issue is resolved, but the image now cuts off at the status bar. Keeping the collapsing toolbar code in the fragment, is there a way to fit the fragment's content to the system window?

Without `fitsSystemWindows` in the activity (preferred behaviour):
[image: Without fitsSystemWindows]

With `fitsSystemWindows` in the activity:
[image]

Comment: Can you show some image of the issue?

Comment: @GPack: Images added.

Comment: And what is the text that sometimes collapses behind the status bar, the title of toolbar maybe?

Comment: Yup. Thank you for walking me through that issue. What looks like the correct behaviour in relation to text is actually removing the padding cut behind the status bar. Looks like the correct way to solve the issue is to add a margin to the toolbar, and to not set the `fitsSystemWindows` flag on the viewpager. I need to find a reliable way to get the status bar height to set this margin, but quickly slapping a `25dp` margin on the top resolves both issues.

Comment: Try changing the FrameLayout to a CoordinatorLayout with `fitsSystemWindows`

Comment: Changing the `FrameLayout` in the activity to a `CoordinatorLayout` doesn't resolve the issue. The `fitsSystemWindow` flag still breaks the window fit in the fragment.

Comment: Maybe it is due to the `fitsSystemWindow` in ViewPager that consumes all the insets.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared, that you want `NestedScrollView` also to `fitSystemWindows`. So, literally, you are prohibiting `WindowInsets` to be passed to children off `NestedScrollView`, thus `ViewPager` is not even aware about `WindowInsets`.

Apply `android:fitSystemWindows="true"` to `NestedScrollView` also.